# Removing unwanted border from UITextfield in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield

I am facing strange `UITextField` border issue in iPad. The below image of textfield looks fine in any iphone.

[image]

But when i open the same app in iPad, the `UITextField` comes up with strange unwanted border in the bottom. See below image for what i am trying to convey. How to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code

```
urTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

Comment: But i want Rounded Rect Border style and do not want to customize it with UIViews and Corner Radius

Answer (score 0):

attributes set for ipad for textfield as shown in image and it is displaying proper in ipad .may be you have set wrong image for ipad or did something else.

[image: attributes set for ipad for textfield]

Comment: No, i havent set any background image in textfield.. Also the app device is set to iPhone so i haven't written any special code for iPad.